# Complement of $c_{0}$ in $\ell^{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

How can I show that $c_{0}$ cannot be complemented in $\ell^{\infty}$?
Complement in the following sense

$$c_{0}+V = \ell^{\infty}$$

And the projections are continuous.

Comment: This is called Phillips's lemma. A nice proof can be found in Robert Whitley, *[Projecting $m$ onto $c_0$](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2315346)*, The American Mathematical Monthly
Vol. **73** (3) (Mar., 1966), pp. 285-286. But most texts on basic functional analysis contain a proof, e.g. Conway.

Comment: The original reference is Phillips, *[On linear transformations](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1940-0004094-3)*, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. **48** (1940), 516-541, see 7.5 on page 539.

Answer (score 23):

This is usually called Phillips's lemma and was proved in 7.5 on page 539 of Phillips, *[On linear transformations](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1940-0004094-3)*, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. **48** (1940), 516–541 (it was also discovered by Sobczyk around the same time).

A somewhat different proof was given by Whitley in *[Projecting $m$ onto $c_0$](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2315346)*, The American Mathematical Monthly
Vol. **73** (3) (Mar., 1966), pp. 285–286. The proof given there is as follows (I'm following the exposition of Albiac–Kalton, *[Topics in Banach space theory](http://books.google.ch/books?id=FkjCulO5xg0C)*, pp 45f with some minor modifications):

1. > Let $S$ be a countable infinite set. Then there is an uncountable “almost disjoint family” of infinite subsets of $S$: more precisely, there is a family $\{A_i\}_{i \in I}$ of subsets of $S$ such that $\# I = \# \mathbb{R}$, that $\# A_i = \# \mathbb{N}$ for all $i$ and the intersection $A_i \cap A_j$ is finite whenever $i \neq j$.

   Identify $S$ with the rational numbers in $[0,1]$ and let $I = [0,1] \smallsetminus S$. For each $i \in I$ choose a sequence $a^{(i)}_n \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} i$ from $S$ and set $A_i = \{a^{(i)}_{n}\,:\,n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ — an infinite set because $i$ is irrational. Then $\# I = \# \mathbb{R}$ and $A_i \cap A_j$ is finite whenever $i \neq j$, as desired.
2. > Let $P: \ell^\infty \to \ell^{\infty}$ be an operator such that $P(x) = 0$ for all $x \in c_0$. Then there is an infinite subset $A$ of $\mathbb{N}$ such that $P(x) = 0$ for all $x$ supported on $A$.

   To see this, consider a family $\{A_i\}_{i \in I}$ of almost disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ as in 1. Assume that for each $i \in I$ we can find $x_i \in \ell^\infty$ supported on $A_i$ such that $P(x_i) \neq 0$, in particular $x_i \notin c_0$. Normalizing $x_i$, we may assume that $\|x_i\|=1$ for all $i \in I$.

   Since $I$ is uncountable there must be $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $I_n = \{i \in I\,:\,(Px_i)(n) \neq 0\}$ is uncountable. Since $I_n$ is uncountable, there must be $k$ such that $I_{n,k} = \{i \in I\,:\,|(Px_i)(n)| \geq 1/k\}$ is uncountable.

   Now fix $n$ and $k$ such that $I_{n,k}$ is uncountable. Let $J \subset I_{n,k}$ be finite and consider $y = \sum_{j \in J} \operatorname{sign}{[(Px_j)(n)]} \cdot x_j$. Note that
   $$
   (Py)(n) = \sum_{j \in J} \operatorname{sign}{[(Px_j)(n)]}\cdot (Px_j)(n) \geq \frac{\# J}{k}
   $$
   by our choice of $y$. Since $A_i \cap A_j$ is finite for $i \neq j$, we can write $y = f + z$ where $f$ has finite support and $\|z\| \leq 1$. Thus $P(y) = P(f) + P(z) = P(z)$ by hypothesis on $P$ and therefore $\|P(y)\| \leq \|P\| \|z\| \leq \|P\|$. This yields
   $$\# J \leq \|P\| k$$
   whence the absurdity that $I_{n,k}$ must be finite.

   It follows that there must be a set $A = A_i$ such that $P(x) = 0$ for all sequences supported in $A$. Since all sets $A_i$ are infinite, $A$ is infinite and we are done.
3. > The subspace $c_0$ of $\ell^\infty$ is not complemented.

   If $c_0$ were complemented in $\ell^\infty$, there would be a continuous projection $Q: \ell^\infty \to \ell^\infty$ with range $c_0$. Applying 2. with $P = 1-Q$ we would find an infinite set $A$ such that $(1-Q)(x) = 0$ for all sequences supported in $A$. But this means that $Q(x) = x$ for all sequences supported in $A$. This is absurd since $A$ is infinite; not all bounded sequences supported in $A$ belong to $c_0$.

Comment: Small terminological glitch: *independent family* has another meaning: all finite Boolean combinations of sets are non-empty. What you have is an *almost disjoint family*.

Comment: Oh, thanks, silly me... I'll fix that in the next edit.

Comment: But is there a continuous map from $\ell^\infty \to c_0$ such that it restricts to identity on $c_0$?

Comment: I don't understand the step where you concluded that $y=f+z$ based on the fact that $A_i\cap A_j$ is finite for $i\neq j$.

Answer (score 7):

Here is my proof.  The weak topology in the space $l^\infty$ is realcompact.  The weak topology in the space $l^\infty/c_0$ is not realcompact.  Therefore $l^\infty/c_0$ is not isomorphic to a closed subspace of $l^\infty$.

Reference for the "weak realcompact" material:
Corson, H. H. The weak topology of a Banach space.  Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 101 1961 1–15.
Edgar, G. A. Measurability in a Banach space. II. Indiana Univ. Math. J. 28 (1979), no. 4, 559–579.

I showed this to W. B. Johnson once, he thought for a minute or so and came up with the more conventional proof.

Comment: Whitley phrases his proof in the following way: the dual of $\ell^\infty$ contains a countable total subset, while the dual of $\ell^\infty/c_0$ does not. The property that the dual contains a countable total subset passes to closed subspaces, hence $\ell^\infty/c_0$ can't be isomorphic to a closed subspace of $\ell^\infty$.

Comment: But is there a continuous map from $\ell^\infty \to c_0$ such that it restricts to identity on $c_0$?