# Example (?) of a Banach space containing an uncomplemented copy of itself

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, examples-counterexamples

I was wondering the following:

> **Background Question:** Does there exist a Banach space $X$ which contains a copy $X_0 \subset X$ of itself that is not complemented?

By "$X_0$ is a copy of $X$", I mean $X_0 \cong X$ via an invertible, bounded, linear map.  Some googling turned up that the answer to the above question is "yes". This [thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140557/quotients-of-linfty) points to a [paper](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/CM/CM_1981__43_1/CM_1981__43_1_133_0/CM_1981__43_1_133_0.pdf) containing an example of an uncomplemented copy of $\ell^1$ in $\ell^1$.  Since the proof seems to depend on some pretty fiddly analysis, and since answering the above question is only incidental to the aims of that paper, I was wondering whether there might be a simpler example of this phenomenon. In particular, I thought that the following example might work:

> **Example(?):** The most famous, and probably the most elementary, example of an uncomplemented subspace is the canonical copy of $c_0$ in $\ell_\infty$. With this in mind, I thought maybe one could use the following:
>   \begin{align*}
> X = c_0 \oplus \ell_\infty \oplus \ell_\infty \oplus \ell_\infty \oplus \ldots && X_0 = \{0\} \oplus c_0 \oplus \ell_\infty \oplus \ell_\infty \oplus \ell_\infty \oplus \ldots 
> \end{align*}
>   The hope is that, if $F \subset X$ was a complement for $X_0$, then this would imply $\pi_2(F) \subset \ell_\infty$ was a complement for $c_0 \subset \ell_\infty$ (a contradiction). Here, $\pi_2$ is projection onto the second factor $X \to \ell_\infty$.

Towards completing the argument, I have already asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1027012/if-e-is-not-complemented-in-x-is-e-oplus-0-not-complemented-in-x-o), but it hasn't attracted much attention. So, I am asking this (hopefully) better motivated question in addition. So, to reiterate, my question is:

> **Question:** Is $\{0\} \oplus c_0 \oplus \ell_\infty \oplus \ell_\infty \oplus \ell_\infty \oplus \ldots$ complemented in $c_0 \oplus \ell_\infty \oplus \ell_\infty \oplus \ell_\infty\oplus \ldots$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the [Banach-Mazur theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Mazur_theorem), each separable Banach space embeds into $C[0,1]$–in particular $C[0,1]\oplus \ell_2$ does. However, no copy of this space in $C[0,1]$ can be complemented, because if it were, so would be $\ell_2$ (as [the relation of being complemented is transitive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1027012/if-e-is-not-complemented-in-x-is-e-oplus-0-not-complemented-in-x-o/1030066#1030066)) but this space is reflexive and $C[0,1]$ has the [Dunford-Pettis property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunford%E2%80%93Pettis_property). Okay, embed now $C[0,1]\oplus \ell_2$ into $C[0,1]$ and form a direct sum with $\ell_2$ to have a concrete example.

Regarding your second question, these two spaces are isomorphic however if you treat the former as a subspace of the latter, then it is not complemented by the [Phillips–Sobczyk](https://eudml.org/doc/38637) theorem.

More generally, if $K$ is a compact metric space such that $C(K)$ is not isomorphic to $c_0$ then $C(K)$ contains an uncomplemented copy of itself (*e.g.*, take $K=[0,1]$). By a result of Bourgain, $\ell_1$ (hence $L_1$ too) contain uncomplemented copies of themselves. The same is true for $\ell_p$ where $p\neq 2,\infty$ as well as for the [Tsirelson space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsirelson_space) and its dual.

To the best of my knowledge the full list of so-far known spaces $X$ with the property that every isomorphic copy of $X$ in $X$ is complemented reads as follows:

- injective Banach spaces, *e.g.*, $\ell_\infty(\Gamma)$ or $C(K)$ where $K$ is extremely disconnected,
- Hilbert spaces (separable or not),
- $c_0(\Gamma)$ for any set $\Gamma$,
- $c_0(\Gamma) \oplus H$ where $H$ is a Hilbert space,
- hereditarily indecomposable Banach spaces and indecomposable $C(K)$-spaces,
- certain finite sums of the above-mentioned spaces but not all sums: $c_0\oplus \ell_\infty$ contains an uncomplemented copy of itself.

Everybody is welcome to extend this list.

Comment: I think I understand most of your first paragraph. You repeatedly use  Fact: "every complemented subspace of a DP space is a DP space". So, by this fact, $C[0,1] \oplus \ell_2$ is not DP since it has a $\ell_2$ as a complemented subspace, and $\ell_2$ is not DP. By the same fact, since $C[0,1]$ is DP and $C[0,1] \oplus \ell_2$ is not DP, any copy (and such exist) of $C[0,1] \oplus \ell_2$ in $C[0,1]$ must be uncomplemented. **However**, I don't see how $X=C[0,1] \oplus \ell_2$ being uncomplemented in $Y=C[0,1]$ implies that $X$ is also uncomplemented in $Y \oplus \ell_2$. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Ah OK I see. If $X \subset Y \subset Z$ and $X$ is complemented in $Z$, then $X$ is also complemented in $Y$. I [had asked](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1027012/if-e-is-not-complemented-in-x-is-e-oplus-0-not-complemented-in-x-o/1030066#1030066) basically this question previously, but somehow was stuck on it. Although I now see it is quite trivial.

Comment: One more question: in your second paragraph, by "Sobczyk's theorem" do you mean the fact that $c_0$ is not complemented in $\ell_\infty$? I know this as "Phillip's Lemma", but I understand Sobczyk proved it around the same time, from reading t.b.'s answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132520/complement-of-c-0-in-ell-infty).

Answer (score 2):

Tomek's answer is very comprehensive. However, I thought I would add a "lower level" explanation.

> **Proposition:** $\{0\} \oplus c_0 \oplus \ell_\infty \oplus \ell_\infty \oplus \ell_\infty \oplus \ldots$ is not complemented in $c_0 \oplus \ell_\infty \oplus \ell_\infty \oplus \ell_\infty\oplus \ldots$.

The idea is to use the following simple lemma:

> **Lemma:** Let $X \subset Y \subset Z$ be nested Banach spaces.
>
> 1. If $X$ is complemented in $Z$, then $X$ is complemented in $Y$.
> 2. If $Y$ is complemented in $Z$, then $Y/X$ is complemented in $Z/X$.

Now we prove the proposition as follows.

- Suppose that $\{0\} \oplus c_0 \oplus \ell_\infty \oplus \ell_\infty \oplus \ell_\infty \oplus \ldots$ is complemented in $c_0 \oplus \ell_\infty \oplus \ell_\infty \oplus \ell_\infty\oplus \ldots$.
- Using (2) to quotient out $\{0\} \oplus \{0\}\oplus \ell_\infty \oplus \ell_\infty \oplus \ldots$, we get that $\{0\} \oplus c_0$ is complemented in $c_0 \oplus  \ell_\infty$.
- Using (1), with the intermediate subspace being $\{0\} \oplus \ell_\infty$, we get that $\{0\} \oplus c_0$ is complemented in $\{0\} \oplus \ell_\infty$.
- The latter was equivalent to "the usual copy of $c_0$ is complemented in $\ell_\infty$", which contradicts Phillip's Lemma.