# Extension of bounded operators between norm spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two Banach Spaces and $X_1$ be a subspace of $X$. If $T$ is a bounded linear operator from $X_1\to Y$, then,

1. this is an extension of $T$ from $X\to Y$ such that $\|T\|_{X}\le
       \|T\|_{X_1}$.
2. The extension is unique if $X_1$ is dense in $X$.

Could some please help with the proof? Or provide a reference where I can find an answer. I have been flipping through all my text and urgently need something quick when studying the chapter of Sobolev space.(There are quite a few extension theorem I've seen in books. However every version is slightly different. Hence I hope someone can guide me through as an example.)

Comment: I don't quite understand the first part of the question. You have $T$ defined on the $X_1 \subset X$. Do you want to extend $T$ now on the whole space? 
In your sentence, do you mean: '1. this is a restriction of $T$ from $X\to Y$'?

Comment: First, yes, want T on whole space. Second, an extension of T (no typos there)

Comment: I read it as $T: X_1 \to Y$ is an extension of $T: X\to Y$. For me, this makes no sense. Please clarify this.

Comment: take a look at page 5 lemma 1.3 in http://www.math.pitt.edu/~xfc/PDEII/Notes01Sp.pdf

Comment: I think it is not correct. 1. How can it be an extension if it is defined on a smaller set than the operator you want to extend. As the name suggest, the domain of the extension should be larger than the previous domain. 2. Assume there is a typo, i.e. 'this' meant to be 'there', then the statement is still false as my answer suggests.

Comment: Anything still unclear?

Answer (score 1):

The following claim is ***not*** true in general.

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and $X_1 \subset X$ a subspace. If $T: X_1 \to Y$ is a continuous bounded operator, then there exists a continuous linear extension to the whole space $X$, i.e. there exists a bounded linear operator $\hat T: X \to Y$ such that $ \hat{T}\restriction_{X_1} = T$.

Take for example $X=\ell^\infty$ $X_1 = c_0$ and $Y=c_0$. Now, the identity $\text{id}: c_0\to c_0$ is clearly a bounded linear operator but has no bounded extension to $\ell^\infty$. If we had one, this would be a continuous decomposition of the form $\ell^\infty = c_0 \oplus V$. This cannot happen due to Phillip's lemma, see this [MSE thread.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132520/complement-of-c-0-in-ell-infty)

However, if $X_1\subset X$ is a dense subspace then there is a unique continuous extension. This is essentially the [continuous linear extension theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_linear_extension) In general, there exist also unbounded extensions, however, only one bounded extension.

Comment: Without a dense subspace $X_1$, I think the first part of the conclusion still hold. Right?

Comment: What I really asked for help is to prove just the first statement, i.e. existence of such an extension, not necessarily uniqueness yet.

Comment: The existence statement still holds even if the subspace is not dense, and it's basically the Hahn-Banach Theorem.

Comment: @Curran As this answer shows, this is not true. Hahn-Banach only holds if the codomain is the scalar field. For a given space $Y$, this property holds for all $X_1\subset X$ and $T\colon X_1\to Y$ if and only $Y$ is a so-called $1$-injective Banach space, which in turn is equivalent to $Y$ being isometrically isomorphic to $C(K)$ for some extremally disconnected compact space $K$.