# Linear transformation $T$ such that for every extension $\overline{T}$, $\|\overline{T}\|>\|T\|$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $E$ and $F$ be normed spaces such that $\dim F < \infty$, $G$ a subspace of $E$ and $T:G\rightarrow F$ a continuous linear map. I know that there exists a continuous linear extension $\overline{T}:E\rightarrow F$. Also, if $E$ is a Hilbert space, then $\overline{T}$ can be chosen in the way that $\|\overline{T}\|=\|T\|$.

> **Problem:** Find an example of $E$, $F$, $G$ and $T$ (like above) such that every continuous linear extension $\overline{T}$ has a greater norm, i.e. $\|\overline{T}\|>\|T\|$.

---

Now, $F$ must be at least a 2-dimensional space, otherwise I could use Hahn-Banach to find an extension with equal norm.  My professor told me it could be done with $E$ of finite dimension. Of course, I tried to come up with an example of $E$ with a norm that doesn't satisfy the parallelogram law. For example, $E=\left(\mathbb{R}^3,\|\cdot\|_{\infty}\right)$ and $F=\left(\mathbb{R}^2,\|\cdot\|_1\right)$. But I couldn't prove that it works with any example I tried using those spaces.

Can somebody help me to find an example and assure that it really has that property?

**EDIT:**
Apparently, it can't be done with $E$ of finite dimension nor with $F$ equipped with the $\sup$ norm, as @Hamza proved below.

Comment: "otherwise I could use Hahn-Banach to find an extension with equal norm" ---> Are you assuming that $T$ is not $0$?

Comment: @ajotatxe I'm afraid i'm not. I don't know how it helps, but I'm sure not looking for trivial examples, if that's the case (i'm still a newbie in functional analysis). =)

Comment: @JoãoVictorBateliRomão You probably should start by looking for trivial examples :)

Comment: @ajotatxe But using $T=0$, then $\overline{T} = 0$ is a counterexample of an extension, right?

Comment: @Neal I'm really having difficulty with this problem. I couldn't find any trivial examples at all. I can't even prove that this example exists. I going to start a bounty.

Comment: I know one, i'll give it once i get home

Comment: @ZelosMalum Thanks. I'll be waiting.

Comment: Am I missing something? Any operator $T : G \to F$ that extends, first extends uniquely to $S : \overline{G} \to F$ by uniform continuity with the same operator norm. Now extend $S$ by sending everything else to $0$. Then $\overline{S} : E \to F$ has the same operator norm as $T$. So it is only possible for the statement to be vacuously true (which has plenty of easy examples).

Comment: @EricThoma You mean false, right? If this case is correct, then $\|\overline{S}\|=\|T\|$, right? What do you mean by "sending everything else to $0$"? You mean $0$ in the rest of the basis of $E$?

Comment: I mean true. If $T$ extends to $E$ (or $\overline{G}$), then it can be extended with the same norm. If $T$ does not extend, then the statement is vacuously true (every extension of $T$ has greater norm, since there are no extensions of $T$). By "sending everything else to $0$", I mean as you say.

Comment: Maybe the Hamel basis part of "sending everything else to $0$" is not so easy or possible, and we are not in Banach spaces so I can't even talk about $\overline{G}$ as a subset of $E$.

Comment: @EricThoma meabe you will need the fact that $G$ has a topological  supplementary in $E$ to extend $T$ by $0$ to a continuous operator

Answer (score 4):

Let $E=\mathbb R^3$, equipped with the sup norm, namely
$$
  \|(x,y,z)\|_\infty  = \max\{|x|, |y|, |z| \},
  $$
and let
$$
  F=G=\{(x, y, z)\in E : x+y+z=0\},
  $$
equipped with the induced norm from $E$.  Also let
$$
  T:G\to F
  $$
be the identity function.  Then clearly $\|T\|=1$, but any extension $\bar T:E\to F$ has norm strictly bigger than
one.
The reason is that any such  $\bar T$ is necessarily  a projection from $E$ to $G$ and there is no
such projection with norm $1$.
The best way to convince oneself of this fact  is to make a cardboard
model of this cube
[image]

cut it along the red line, place one of the two halves on top of the table with the red hexagon down,
[image]
and attempt to shine a flashlight so that the shadow is restricted to within the hexagon.  It is impossible!

---

This is based on another answer I recently gave to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4019880/extension-of-operator-t-from-a-subspace-y-of-x-to-mathbbrn-incomple/4021187#4021187).

Comment: You made those diagrams yourself! Frankly , magnificent stuff from you in both answers, +1

Comment: Thank you @Teresa!

Answer (score 2):

If $G$ have a topological complimentary in  $E$ (in particular if $E$ is finite dimensional space) i don't think that such construction can be done, because prolonging by $0$ on the complementary space, will have the same norme :
$$
\|\hat{T}\|=\sup_{\begin{array}{c} x\in E \\ x\neq 0\end{array}} \frac{\|\hat{T}x\|}{\|x\|}=\sup_{\begin{array}{c} x=z+y \\ y,z\neq 0\end{array}} \frac{\|\hat{T}z+\hat{T}y\|}{\|z+y\|}=\sup_{\begin{array}{c}  z\in G\\y\in E-G \\ y,z\neq 0\end{array}} \frac{\|Tz\|}{\|z+y\|}=\sup_{\begin{array}{c}  z\neq 0\end{array}} \frac{\|Tz\|}{\|z\|}=\|T\|
$$
If now $E$ is infinite dimensional and $G$ a closed subspace but with no complaiment in $E$, let for example :
$$
\begin{array}{}
I&:& c_0& \to &l_\infty\\
 & & x &\mapsto & x
 \end{array}
$$
so by a famous [Phillips's lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132520/complement-of-c-0-in-ell-infty) $I$ can't be extended to a continuous linear maps in $l_\infty$.

but if $F$ is finite dimensional space i don't have an explicit example but as remarks you can't take the infinite norm as norm to $F$ in fact, let $T :G \to \mathbb{R}^n $, and let $(T_1,T_2,\dots,T_n)$ it composite then it's clear that $\|Tx\|=\sup_{i\leq n}|T_ix|$, so let $\hat{T}=(\hat{T_1},\dots,\hat{T}_n)$ be the preserving norm extension given by Hahn-Banach theorem   :
$$
\|\hat{T}\|=\sup_{ x\in S_E } \|\hat{T}x\|=\sup_{ x\in S_E } (\sup_{i\leq n}\|\hat{T}_ix\|)=\sup_{i\leq n}(\sup_{ x\in S_E } \|\hat{T}_ix\|)=\sup_{i\leq n} \|T_i\|)=\|T\|
$$ 
 we call this propriety the injectivity of Banach space, and it prove that a finite dimensional space is injective if and only if he is isomorphe isometrically to $l^\infty_n$

Comment: Interesting! Specially the fact that $I$ can't be extended to a continuous linear map. I have some notes of Functional Analysis with an exercise that I solved asking to prove that there is a version of Hahn-Banach Theorem for linear maps into $l_{\infty}$. I must have suppose that the subspace have a complement somewhere in the passages of my proof.

Comment: for the case of $l_\infty$ it's not necessary to suppose that you have a complement but you can use the second remark about decomposition, but your decomposition will be infinite and the same reasoning will work in this case

Comment: @João, I think Hamza's mistake is in the penultimate step of the first displayed calculation.

Comment: I think @Ruy is correct. Think to $E=\mathbb R^2$. If $G$ is the $X$-axis, and $L$ is any complent different from $Y$-axis, say the line with slope $(10000000,1)$, then the projection of $(0,1)$ on $G$ along $L$ has huge norm. So extending $T$ by setting it zero on $L$ does not work.