# Sequences converging to zero do not have a complement in $l^\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis

I know that given a closed subspace $M$ of a Hilbert space $H$, we can find a closed omplement $N$ of $M$ such that $H=M\oplus N$. I was trying to see when this property holds for Banach spaces too.

Coming to the question, given $c_0$, the space of complex sequences converging to zero, looked upon as a closed subspace of $(l^\infty, |. |_\infty)$, does there exist such a complement? If no, why not? And if yes, can it be explicitly described?

Comment: No, it isn't. You can find the, non-trivial, proof in various texts on Banach Space theory.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132520/complement-of-c-0-in-ell-infty).