# Complement of a Banach space in its double dual.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

A closed subspace $E$ of a Banach space $X$ is said to complemented if there exists a closed subspace $F$ of $X$ such that $E+F=X$ and $E\cap F=\{0\}$.
I was thinking whether $X$ is complemented in $X^{**}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. For example $c_0$ is not complemented in its double dual $l^\infty$ (with detailed reasons [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132520/complement-of-c-0-in-ell-infty)). But it is true that $X^*$ is always complemented in $X^{***}$. (and by this $c_0$ cannot be isomorphic to a dual space)

Comment: Can you remark how one can see $X^*$ being complemented in $X^{***}$? Is this  an iff statement? (ie does there exist a Banach space without a pre-dual but that is complemented in $X^{**}$?)

Comment: The transposed of the inclusion into the second dual is a projection. $L^1 [0,1]$ is not a dual space but complemented in its bidual.